# Azure Data Factory Copy data activity not copying all the records

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have built a adf pipeline which fetches json data from rest api and loads into a table in Azure synapse. Everything is working fine but i have observed that it only copying 1 record.

[image]

When I checked the same request using postman, i can see more than 900 records coming in json. Can someone help me understand what is happening and how can i resolve this?

Comment: Could you please add the information about the REST resource configurations in copy activity source and copy sink?

Answer (score 0):

Check the source and sink make sure you are not checking the first row only field in the source.